# set sprite to current animation texture

Tags: animation, libgdx, box2d

In my game I have some box2d bodies where I add sprites using the following code in my `render()` method.

```
for (Body body : worldBodies) {
        if (body.getUserData() instanceof Sprite) {
            Sprite sprite = (Sprite) body.getUserData();

            Vector2 position = body.getPosition();
            sprite.setPosition(position.x - sprite.getWidth() / 2 , position.y - sprite.getHeight() / 2);
            sprite.setRotation(body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
            sprite.draw(batch);
        }
    }
```

One of the bodies has to be animated.

```
birdAnimation = new Animation(1, birdAtlas.getRegions());
birdAnimation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_PINGPONG);
```

This is the animation and now I tried to set the body's sprite `obstacle6` to the current textureRegion from the Animation unsing this code:

```
obstacle6.setRegion(birdAnimation.getKeyFrame(delta));
```

Somehow it just shows the first texture of the atlas. How can I get it to change? Or is there an other way to animate a box2d body?
If you need any other information just comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getKeyFrame` method needs elapsed time, not delta time.